# Subquery com And

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
+--------+---------+
|Nome    | telefone|
+--------+---------|
|João    |   Iphone|
|João    |  Samsung|
|Marcio  |   Xiaomi|
|Carol   |   Iphone|
|Adriana |  Samsung|
+--------+---------+
```

E preciso retornar as pessoas que se enquadram em 2 cenários distintos:

1- Qe tenham **apenas Iphone**

2 - Que tenham a **combinação exclusiva de Iphone E Samsung**; Ou seja, esta é a saída esperada:

```
+--------+
|Nome    |
+--------+
|João    |
|Carol   |
+--------+
```

Abaixo minha tentativa:

```
select nome
from exemplo
where telefone = 'Iphone' or
telefone in 
    (select telefone 
    from exemplo
    where telefone = 'Iphone' and telefone = 'Samsung')
```

Comment: Iphone E Samsung apenas , ou pode ter outros ?

Comment: Aqueles que tenham apenas Iphone OU aqueles que tenham a combinação exclusiva de Iphone E samsung

Answer (score -1):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando o operador *Exists* para verificar se a pessoa possui telefones diferentes dos especificados:

```
select t.nome
from exemplo as t
where 
    t.telefone = 'Iphone' and
    not exists
        (select s.telefone 
         from exemplo as s
         where 
             s.nome = t.nome and
             s.telefone not in ('Iphone', 'Samsung'))
```

Comment: Correta , pq negativam ? Só pq não está num "fiddle" ?!

Comment: Opa @imex Na verdade não tá funcionando, mas realmente o pessoal é muito chato. Minha pergunta tomou 3 downvotes e nem sei o porquê

Comment: Não funcionou? O que aconteceu exatamente? Foi exibida alguma mensagem de erro? Não retornou o resultado esperado?

Comment: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f03c2/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f03c2/1)

Answer (score -4):

Olá, tente a seguinte query

```
select nome
from exemplo
where telefone = 'Iphone'
and telefone in ('Iphone','Samsung')
```